# JCenter and Bintray not in Sync

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I published a Scala library in [Bintray](https://bintray.com/angelcervera/maven/osm4scala/1.0), for Scala 2.11 and 2.10

But in [JCenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/acervera/osm4scala/), it is only available the Scala 2.10 version.

I thought that it was in sync automatically, but looks like I was wrong.

Any idea how to sync both repositories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when changing the artifact path you won't be able to resolve your content through JCenter although it was previously included. 
The reason for this is that the inclusion of your scala library in JCenter is for the files’ path.
Therefore, it was originally included under the path prefix 'com/acervera/osm4scala/osm4scala-core_2.10'.

However, we have re-linked your scala library on the GroupId level so your versions will be synchronized automatically:
'osm4scala-core_2.10', 'osm4scala-core_2.11', etc..

Guy.