# Bintray and JCenter not in Sync

Tags: bintray, jcenter

after seeing this issue and the way it was solved [JCenter and Bintray not in Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963068/jcenter-and-bintray-not-in-sync) I'm wondering if this is a general or specific problem. I'm having the same issue, I published version 1.2.0 and synced OK, but then I published 1.2.1 and it never made it to JCenter.

I did update the groupId in between releases, may that be related?

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mofiler/

https://bintray.com/btafel/maven/mofiler-sdk

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have relinked your package according to the new GroupID. This is indeed similar to the scenario described in the linked mentioned by you:

The package was included to JCenter under a particular GroupID and changing  that, would need a path prefix change for the inclusion path.

Usually, when a change for the for GroupID of a JCenter linked package is needed, one should create a new package with the updated path in order to preserve consistency of other users depending on the already included artifacts.