# Bintray does not sync one of the artifacts of the package to the jcenter

Tags: publishing, bintray, jcenter

We've published a package with two artifacts in it (`android` and `os`) to Bintray: https://dl.bintray.com/gojuno/maven/com/gojuno/commander/

Then we've enabled sync with jcenter for this package, **but only one of the artifacts is in sync** (`android` is synched while `os` is not):

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/gojuno/commander/

I contacted Bintray through Inbox on bintray.com, Contact Us on bintray.com, Email and Twitter and haven't received reply anywhere, this issue is blocking for the project.

I saw similar issue was resolved through StackOverflow [Bintray and JCenter not in Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983301/bintray-and-jcenter-not-in-sync), so this is my hope.

Answer (score 5):

An inclusion to JCenter always uses an allocated path prefix to avoid accidental file overwrites by other users. However, the 'commander' package contains files with no common base path:
'/com/gojuno/commander/**os**' AND '/com/gojuno/commander/**android**'

The best practice we recommend is creating a new package and not creating more than one path prefix for a package. If you wish keep working like this, please note that you will have to submit an inclusion request for each path prefix.

As for now you may proceed working on the same groupID path prefix with your different sub-modules.

We hope this clarifies.

Comment: This definitely clarifies things and I'm ok with current behavior, however there is no way to request linking other entries in same package through bintray.com UI, once I successfully requested linking of package (I suppose it selected `android` automatically) this button disappeared, can you please add it so it won't be confusing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

usually when changing the artifact path you won't be able to resolve your content through JCenter although it was previously included. 
The reason for this is that the inclusion of your 'commander' package in JCenter is for the files’ path. 
Therefore, it was originally included under the path prefix 'com/gojuno/commander/android/'.

However, we have re-linked your package on the GroupId level (com/gojuno/commander) so every sub-module of your 'commander' package, will be added automatically and be synced with JCenter.

Comment: Yup, I see, though there is a problem with bintray.com ui in this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468385/bintray-does-not-sync-one-of-the-artifacts-of-the-package-to-the-jcenter/43470773#comment74006637_43470773