# Bintray does not link new artifact to Jcenter

Tags: publishing, bintray, jcenter

We have a maven package published to Bintray and linked to Jcenter.

In version 1.1.0 we've added a new artifact to the package: `koptional-reactor-extensions`, and uploaded release to Bintray.

All the artifacts are visible on Bintray without problems: https://dl.bintray.com/gojuno/maven/com/gojuno/koptional/

However Jcenter only shows artifacts that were already published and does not show `koptional-reactor-extensions`: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/gojuno/koptional/

Neither Bintray's Gradle plugin nor Bintray web ui shows why it does not show up and how can we link new artifact to the Jcenter, this is very, very confusing.

P.S. Previously I was able to solve [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468385/bintray-does-not-sync-one-of-the-artifacts-of-the-package-to-the-jcenter) only by asking a question on StackOverflow so I'm doing it here again (I've also contacted Bintray through Inbox on website but with no luck).

And to be clear, I've never had such problems with oss.sonatype.org.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your submitting this issue.

We have managed to resolve the issue you were experiencing.
The issue occurred due to the reason of artifactID that was not approved.

Usually in order to add packages to JCenter, we add only packages under 'groupID/groupID/artifactID'. Usually we approve only one path for package, but since we wanted to expedite the resolution for your issue we decided to approve the package with only groupID. (i.e /com/gojuno/koptional). 
This means that all three artifactIDs (koptional, koptional-reactor-extensions, koptional-rxjava2-extensions) are now approved and synced to JCenter.

We hope this clarifies. Please let us know if you encounter any other issues.

Best Regards, 
Yonatan Brand
JFrog Support

Comment: Hi Yonatan, thank you for resolving the issue! Your explanation definitely clarifies things, however, I'd like to ask is there any way I could understand this myself through Bintray website/etc?

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin Thank you for the following question. 
With regards to your question, please check our documentation on "Promoting Your Material" here: https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_promotingyourmaterial.html

In the above link search for the following: 
"Before you can include your package in JCenter, the following requirements must be met:"

Comment: @YonatanBrand I encountered the same issue with my package `jotaro`. And I can't find any way to reach out bintray on the web UI, so I hope it will reach you here.
I really wish bintray would address this issue, since it basically reproduces even after 2 years since this question was posted.

Comment: @Alviere Thank you for reaching out. 
I have managed to resolve the issue for you as well. 
I will raise this again to our Product-Team. 

Also, you can always contact JFrog Support using email to support@jfrog.com. 

I hope this helps! Please let me know if you have any follow up questions or issues.

Comment: @YonatanBrand hello, I asked to Bintray support and they recommend me to create a new package with the new artifact for the new target. My library is a Kotlin Multiplatform project. 

This is an awful solution because I will have tons of packages if I gradually add each package. They also don't recommend the merging of packages too (JCenter link can break). Uploading a new version with the Gradle plugin maven-publish will be a pain in the ass...

I think there should be a way to force JCenter to checks if a package has new artifacts or a guide about how to merge without breaking this link.