# Bintray and Jcenter are not synchronized

Tags: publishing, bintray, jcenter

For two Bintray packages, we're publishing multiple artifacts in:

- `com.criteo.mediation.mopub:criteo-adapter` and `com.criteo.mediation.mopub:criteo-adapter-development` for https://dl.bintray.com/criteo/mobile/com/criteo/mediation/mopub/
- `com.criteo.mediation.google:criteo-adapter` and `com.criteo.mediation.google:criteo-adapter-development` for https://dl.bintray.com/criteo/mobile/com/criteo/mediation/google/

But only the two `criteo-adapter-development`artifacts are synchronized on JCenter:

- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/criteo/mediation/mopub/
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/criteo/mediation/google/

The expectation is to get all artifacts to be synchronized.
We have another package with a similar setup that is working well currently: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/criteo/publisher/

I saw other similar issues on SO such as [Bintray does not sync one of the artifacts of the package to the jcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43468385), but unfortunately, there seems that we cannot take any action except posting a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you submit a JCenter inclusion request for a particular package, all the artifactIDs present under the groupID will be included in the JCenter. If you add additional artifactIDs under the groupID , which is already linked to JCenter , those artifactIDs will not be mirrored in JCenter because JCenter hosts Single path for a single package.

In your case for the package "[publisher-sdk-mopub-adapters](https://bintray.com/criteo/mobile/publisher-sdk-mopub-adapters)", there are two artifactIDs under the groupID com/criteo/mediation/mopub
criteo-adapter
criteo-adapter-development

Only the first artifactID criteo-adapter-development is included in JCenter, In order to add the other artifactID, create a new Bintray package and include all the files under the path GroupID+ artifactID i.e com/criteo/mediation/mopub/criteo-adapter-development so that the package will be hosted in JCenter under the path https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/criteo/mediation/mopub/

Comment: This adds complexity in publication scripts, and the worst, is that it would break uniformisation of them. Is there a way to request again the sync of a bintray package to jcenter ?