# Scala library, Bintray not syncing versions to JCenter

Tags: scala, artifactory, bintray, jcenter

I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40963068/1003665) but couldn't understand any action to take. I have two open-source scala libraries - I published the second one just yesterday. Everything looks good on the Bintray repo, but only one version makes it to jCenter.

https://dl.bintray.com/ticofab/maven/io/ticofab/ :

```
aws-request-signer_2.10/
aws-request-signer_2.11/
aws-request-signer_2.12/   <-- latest scala version, missing later
reactive-kraken_2.11/
reactive-kraken_2.12/      <-- latest scala version, missing later
```

http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/ticofab/ :

```
aws-request-signer_2.11/
reactive-kraken_2.11/
```

Is there a way I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your submitting this issue.

We have managed to resolve the issue you were experiencing. The issue occurred due to a bad link to JCenter.

Usually in order to add packages to JCenter, we add only packages under 'groupID/groupID/artifactID'. Since Scala packages are different and they contain versions of their own we needed to change the link to groupID only without artifactID (groupID/groupID. i.e /io/ticofab).

This means that all artifactIDs (reactive-kraken_2.11, reactive-kraken_2.12, aws-request-signer_2.10, aws-request-signer_2.11, aws-request-signer_2.12) are now approved and synced to JCenter.

We hope this clarifies. Please let us know if you encounter any other issues.

Best Regards, 
Yonatan Brand 
JFrog Support

Comment: Thank you very much! I assume you guys fixed it so that it will just work smoothly in the future :)